# Properly buffering and validating string

Tags: c

I am getting a bit of an error in my program, it is somewhat basic but here is my error: I am trying to properly input a series of strings into a structure and it seems like user input is ending at the wrong spot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define buffer 256
struct Fisher
 {
 char  SSN[8]; //9 digit max
 char First_Name[12];
 char Last_Name[15];
 char Phone[10];
 char Email[35];
 }typedef Fisher;

void getFisher(Fisher* pfisher, int i);
void dispFisher(Fisher* pfisher, int i);
void Fisherman_Menu(Fisher* pfisher, int i);
int main()
{
int i = 0;
   Fisher fisherarray[3];
   Fisher* pfisher = &fisherarray[0];
   Fisherman_Menu(pfisher, i);
   return 0;
}
void Fisherman_Menu(Fisher* pfisher, int i)
{

    for(;;)
    {
fflush(stdin);
        printf("-1-Register Fisherman\n");
        printf("-2-Search Fisherman\n");
        printf("-3-Go back to Main Menu\n");
fflush(stdin);
        int choice=0;
        scanf(" %d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1)
        {
         fflush(stdin);
            getFisher(pfisher, i);
            i++;
        }
        if (choice == 2)
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                dispFisher(pfisher, i);
            }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            break;  /* Break out of loop */
        }
        else
            printf("Anything else?\n");
    }

    /* When this function returns, you get back to the main menu */
}
void getFisher(Fisher* pfisher, int i)
{
    char input[buffer];
    char* pinput = NULL;
    //===============================
    printf("Enter Social Security Number: ");
    pinput = fgets(input, buffer, stdin);//validate
    strcpy((pfisher+i)->SSN, pinput);
    //(pfisher+i)->SSN = atoi(pinput);

    //==============================
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    pinput = fgets(input, buffer, stdin);//validates name
    strcpy((pfisher+i)->First_Name, pinput);

    //==============================
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    pinput = fgets(input, buffer, stdin);//validates name
            strcpy((pfisher+i)->Last_Name, pinput);

    //==============================
    printf("Enter phone number as a 10 digit number (without any    
        dashes     or spaces): ");
    pinput = fgets(input, buffer, stdin);//validate phone
        strcpy((pfisher+i)->Phone, pinput);
        //(pfisher+i)->Phone = atoi(pinput);

        //===============================
        printf("Enter email address: ");
        pinput = fgets(input, 20, stdin);//validates name
        strcpy((pfisher+i)->Email, pinput);
    }
    void dispFisher(Fisher* pfisher, int i)
    {
    int len;
    int pen;
     printf("ssn is equal to: %s\n", ((pfisher+0)->SSN));
     printf("First Name is equal to: %s\n", ((pfisher+0)->First_Name));
     printf("ssn is equal to: %s\n", ((pfisher+1)->SSN));
      printf("First Name is equal to: %s\n", ((pfisher+1)->First_Name));

    len = strlen(((pfisher+0)->SSN));
    printf("string length = %d\n", len);
    pen = strlen(((pfisher+1)->SSN));
    printf("string length = %d\n", len);
    /*
        int arr = 0;
        char searchSSN[9];
        printf("Enter SSN: ");
              scanf("%s", &searchSSN);

              for(arr = 0; arr < i; arr++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(&searchSSN, (pfisher+arr)->SSN) == 0)

                {

        //printf("I is equal to: %s\n", (pfisher+i)->SSN);
        printf("Fisher\n");
        printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("%d \n %s \n %s \n %s \n %s ", (pfisher + arr)->SSN, ((pfisher+arr)->First_Name), ((pfisher+arr)->Last_Name), ((pfisher+arr)->Phone), (pfisher+arr)->Email);
        printf("-------------------------------------------\n");

    }


      }

    */
    }
```

My output for SSN is getting messed up and becoming "123456789(FirstName string)
example: 123456789TurboTurkey
How can I clean up the length of the string and get in the SSN properly

Comment: `char  SSN[8];` should be `char  SSN[10];`. (9 digits + NUL character)

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` causes undefined behavior

Comment: Changing it to Char SSN[10] leaves the '\0' in the First name causing it to skip.  Please present code or test your solutions, I have been testing everything simple for over 16 hours.  I am very tired

Comment: @TurboTurkey I am tired of code dumps with no test results and  apparent attempt at debugging.  'the results still aren't appropriate output' is not helpful.  Also, stop bean-counting and just make all those strings [64].  'Please present code or test your solutions' - why can YOU not test them and run them under your debugger to find out what is going wrong?

Comment: @TurboTurkey this not a programming service. You should trim your test case into a short example that shows what's going wrong, and clearly documents what the problem is.

Comment: Congratulations!  I'd not seen `typedef` abused like this before ——  `struct Fisher
 {
 char  SSN[8]; //9 digit max
 char First_Name[12];
 char Last_Name[15];
 char Phone[10];
 char Email[35];
 } typedef Fisher;`.  Normally, `typedef` goes at the start of the declaration.  I was going to say "doesn't compile", but I'm relieved I checked.  That said, it is appalling style to write it thus.  Don't do it.  The storage class (`static`, `extern`, `register`, `auto` — on second thoughts, don't ever use `auto` in C — `_Thread_local` and `typedef`) should be first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough space to store 9 digit in SSN. If you want to store 9 digit in it, its size should be 10 (9 digit + `NULL`). If there is no `NULL` charactor, it will read near by locations too..

Comment: I have changed the code to char[10] before, If you do it the results still aren't appropriate output.

Comment: What was the result then? What was your input?

Comment: Can you give what actually required and what you got with an example?

Comment: @TurboTurkey: Remember, `fgets()` returns the newline too; you need to strip that off before copying to the target string.  You also need to check that `pinput` is not null before using it; null indicates that you reached EOF or got a read error of some sort.  It seems a bit odd to use `(pfisher+i)->Email` rather than `pfisher[i].Email`.  You should check that your `scanf()` calls succeed too; in fact, you should check that all inputs work.  It's conventional to use UPPERCASE for macros, and `buffer` is usually the name of a variable, not a constant as with `#define buffer 256`.

Comment: The input for SSN: 0123456789 and then the next line requesting first name was Name, results were printed out as (pfisher+i)->SSN 0123456789Name what can i do to strip the new line?

Comment: There might be a problem if you are using `gcc` compiler becouse you used `fgets` after `scanf`. Here the new line character automatically go as input to `fgets` leads your program will not wait for `SSN`. Are you faced this problem?